# How can I test if a URL is a valid image (in javascript)?

Tags: javascript, forms, image

When submitting a form, I want to make sure a field is a valid image URL.

I could make an AJAX endpoint on my server which CURLs the URL and parses the output with an image library, but that feels a bit of overkill.

Could I get away with making an `<img>` element then synchronously check the response somehow?

Comment: I'm sure this is a dupe... let me see if I can dig it up...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can make an `<img>` element and handle its `onerror` and `onload` events.

If the `load` event fires, it's a valid image; if the `error` event fires, it isn't.
This even works across domains.

Comment: are those guaranteed to fire in a timely manner (in every major browser)? Will I have to do some timeout logic for myself?

Comment: I couldn't get the onerror or on onload events to fire an img tag. According to w3schools these are not supported events. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_img.asp

Comment: Very nice and simple answer

Answer (score 5):

Do this, the following code will replace any non-image with a default image.

```
<img src="xx" onerror="this.src = '/images/default.png'">
```

Comment: This works well - one slight grammar mistake - you are missing a double quote - that I will edit for you.