# How to check that url is a valid image source using Jquery?

Tags: jquery, image, validation

I want to check if an image exists on the given URL using jquery. For example how do I check that an image exists on this url.

```
https://www.google.com/logos/2012/hertz-2011-hp.gif
```

but not on this url

```
 http://www.google.com
```

Comment: see [there](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/169625/regex-to-check-if-valid-url-that-ends-in-jpg-png-or-gif), [there](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3381663/check-if-image-exists-with-given-url-using-jquery) and [there](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4669111/is-this-a-valid-test-to-check-if-a-url-refers-to-an-image-in-js-jquery) it will be useful

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3646914/how-do-i-check-if-file-exists-in-jquery-or-javascript) is what you may be looking for.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
function IsValidImageUrl(url) {
$("<img>", {
    src: url,
    error: function() { alert(url + ': ' + false); },
    load: function() { alert(url + ': ' + true); }
});
}

IsValidImageUrl("https://www.google.com/logos/2012/hertz-2011-hp.gif");
IsValidImageUrl("http://google.com");
```

Comment: Have you tested this? For some reason I am trying to use this code in chrome and every thing is coming back false

Comment: oh, what's happening is this load executes in a separate thread. I was trying to return true false from the error load methods which wouldn't work.