# javascript getting google-plus user avatar

Tags: javascript, google-plus

stackoverflow'ers!
So my job now is to work around social networks. I've made login for facebook, google and twitter. Now i need to retrieve user avatars. Site is very dynamic and pretty much everything are working through javascript and ajax. I have got facebook user avatar successfully. When user has avatar, it returns avatar, when user has no avatar, it returns facebook's default avatar. Now im working on google-plus and twitter. I found nice url, where i can get avatar from google-plus:

```
    https://plus.google.com/s2/photos/profile/{oauth_id}?sz=100
```

I am storing oauth_id in session, it is accessible. 
When user has set avatar - everything works fine. Problem is, when users avatar is'nt set - that link returns 404 error.
How can i determine in jquery or just javascript, if that link returns 404 error or not?
And for some future work - i think twitter has the same problem.
Or may be you could provide some better options to achieve this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another way to do this is to request the plus.me scope, authenticate the user, then retrieve their profile which will have the image value set if they have an avatar. I created a live demo here: http://wheresgus.com/profile.html which shows profile retrieval using the Google+ public data API.

To set things up for your project, go to the Google APIs console - https://code.google.com/apis/console/ and create a project with the Google+ API enabled. You will need the Client ID for a web application from the API Access section of the Google APIs console.

The relevant code is as follows:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function onSignin(e){
      accessToken = e.access_token;
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.open('GET', "https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me/");
      xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + accessToken);
      xhr.send();

      xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if (this.readyState == 4){
          var myProfile = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
          alert(myProfile.image.url);
        }
      }
    }
    </script>      
  </head>
  <body>
    <g:plus action="connect" clientid="YOUR CLIENT ID" scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me" callback="onSignin">
    </g:plus>
  </body>
</html>
```

Create an HTML file with this code and replace YOUR CLIENT ID with the credentials you created in the Google APIs console.  When you click the sign in button, the client will give you a URL for the user.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the jquery.ajax() or jquery.get() method (or something similar), you should be able to check the jqXHR object that is returned as part of the callback. It has a "status" field which contains the status code for the HTTP call.

See the section **The jqXHR Object** under http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: If i put my given link in ajax, it always returns error. Maybe because it redirects to actual .png(if exists). So im still stuck on this.

Comment: I don't understand then. You're getting a 404 error meaning "not found". If there is no avatar image, then the image is "not found".

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Ak5cS/ At first, i put 2 paths in img tags. One works, other dont. Then when you click on link, it passes same paths to ajax, both fails. Maybe i just made it wrong, but, check it out. Another option i found is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4669111/is-this-a-valid-test-to-check-if-a-url-refers-to-an-image-in-js-jquery

Answer (score 0):

I tried to fiddle around with the above suggestions but found the following approach suitable. I used jquery get to fetch the image url. Following is the code snippet.

```
function getImageURL(_gplusid) {
                $.get("https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/"+_gplusid+"?fields=image"+"&key="+googlepluskey,
                function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                });
        }
```

P.S : _gplusid is the google plus id of the user and googlepluskey is your google authentication key. The output is a json object containing the image url. You need to enable google plus api access via google api console.